# "be very much" meaning

Tags: meaning

What does "is very much" means in the following sentence? Is it a common usage?

> Surprisingly, when I asked my teacher, he was very much for the planned excursion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not looking for the meaning of "be very much"; you need the meaning of "be very much for", which is an idiom.

To *be for* something is to *be in favor* of it, to *be an advocate* of it, to *be a proponent* of it.

To modify it with "very much" is what it sounds like: to be particularly strongly or enthusiastically in favor of whatever it is.

In this case, the teacher was surprisingly (to the narrator "I") in favor very strongly of the planned excursion.

Comment: And to "not be for" something is often to "be against" it.